# Twitter gem follow method in rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a method that follows another twitter user, automatically after authorization, using the Twitter gem. This works:

```
def follow_us
     Twitter.follow("boxfirepress")     
end
```

I want, though -- to check and make sure the user isn't already being followed. I can't seem to get the conditionals right.

I tried:

```
def follow_us
     Twitter.follow("boxfirepress") unless Twitter.friendship_exists?("boxfirepress", self.nickname)        
   end
```

Where `self.nickname` is supposed to be the twitter handle captured during the oauth process. It's stored in the database, but maybe it's not being loaded correctly? I'm using an `after_save` call on the `Authorizations` model.

I also tried

```
  def follow_us
       unless Twitter.friendship_exists?("boxfirepress", self.nickname) 
         Twitter.follow("boxfirepress")        
       end
  end
```

But that didn't work, either. I also tried `self.uid` in place of the nickname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother checking first. The verification makes a request to the Twitter API to find if there a friendship exist. If one does not you then have to make a second request to actually follow them. If one does exist you still made a request to the API where as if you just blindly try to follow the account it isn't going to the fact that they friendship already exists.